# Nitpicky ReSharper behavior, null reference with Request.Cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, resharper, nullreferenceexception

This is really a stupid little thing, but I'm anal-retentive, and when R# (6.1) underlines something I generally want to "fix" it.  I'm working on an MVC4 project and am passing an ID value from one controller to another using a cookie.  I'm still a bit of an MVC newbie, so maybe there's a better way to do this.  Either way, I'm checking for the existence of the cookie and then retrieving it's value like this:

```
var idCookieString = string.Empty;
if(Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("id"))
{
    idCookieString = Request.Cookies["id"].Value;
}
```

The annoyance is that R# is calling out the `Request.Cookies["id"]` as a possible null reference exception, even though I'm checking to see if the cookie exists in the `if` statement.  Is there a better way to check to see if a cookie exists before attempting to retrieve it, or should I just put a R# ignore on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R# does not know that Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("id") is in fact a check to see if Request.Cookies["id"].Value will return anything. so yes, you have to either add an R# ignore or add an extra line of useless code:

```
if (Request.Cookies["id"] != null)
```

afaik there is no other way.

Comment: Eesh, that kinda sucks.  I can get it to go away by fetching the cookie itself first and then checking the cookie for null before assigning a value, e.g., `var idCookieString = idCookie == null ? string.Empty : idCookie.Value;`.  You're right about R# not knowing that the `Contains` is handling the null reference check.  Thanks!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but couldn't you have a key that has a null value?  Request.Cookies["id"] = null;  It would still pass the contains test (there is an Id key) but it would be a null value?